# need to call a php script from bash script through eval

Tags: php, bash, eval

I need to run

eval "php /srv/www/scripts/mage/install-invoke-app.php"

which it finds the file, but end up with
[image]

Which is messing up on the `<?php` right off.  Why? How is that fixed?  Googling so far has not produced the right answer.

---

**update**
Here is the script in short, it's a function, then I pass a call back .. there is tons stripped out so just the area only.

in the including base.sh script

```
cd /srv/www/
. scripts/install-functions.sh
#tons of other stuff
cd /srv/www/
. scripts/mage-install.sh
```

in install-functions.sh

```
install_repo(){
    if [ $2 ]
    then
        echo "just 1"
        git clone $1 -q
    else
        echo "just 1 and 2"
        git clone $1 $2 -q
    fi
    success=$?
    if [[ $success -eq 0 ]];
    then
        echo "Repository successfully cloned."
        echo "cleaning"
        cd $r/
        rm -rf LICENSE.txt STATUS.txt README.md RELEASE_NOTES.txt modman
        cd ../
        cp -af $r/* .
        rm -rf $r/
        if [ -z "$3" ]
        then
            echo "no callback"
        else
            eval $3
        fi
    else
        echo "Something went wrong!"
    fi
    sleep 1 # slow it down to insure that we have the items put in place.
}

#declare -A list = ( [repo]=gitUser )
install_repolist(){
    gitRepos=$1
    for r in "${!gitRepos[@]}" #loop with key as the var
    do
        giturl="git://github.com/${gitRepos[$r]}/$r.git"
        echo "Adding $r From $giturl"
        if [ -z "$r" ];
        then
            echo
        else
            install_repo $giturl $2 $3
        fi
        echo
    done
    return 1
}
```

In the scripts/mage-install.sh

```
declare -A gitRepos
#[repo]=gitUser
gitRepos=(
    [wsu_admin_base]=jeremyBass
    [wsu_base_theme]=jeremyBass
    [Storeutilities]=jeremyBass
    [StructuredData]=jeremyBass
)
cd /srv/www/mage/
install_repolist $gitRepos 0 "php /srv/www/scripts/mage/install-invoke-app.php"
unset gitRepos         #unset and re-declare to clear associative arrays
declare -A gitRepos
```

And that is the basic loop here.. I need to call back to a function, but that install_repolist is used in other areas too so I can't hard code it.  If there is a better way then eval, cool

Comment: Without any dynamic variables in your string after "eval", why do you thing you need it? Explain more of your problem.

Comment: *If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question* -- **explain the actual problem**

Comment: I can't understand what you mean by *"which it finds the file, but end up with"*.

Comment: @konsolebox it finds the `install-invoke-app.php` file, but ends up spewing the errors.

Comment: @AmalMurali I made the edit, hope that clears it up, and I if I can drop the eval cool

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC Specifically which functions are those that you can't modify?

Comment: @konsolebox Well I can for the most part change any of them.. but they have to be in the same fashion .. ie, I have to have the files as they are (base.sh is called from vagrant to start it off) and the functions are use many times to get different github repos ..

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC I made a mistake editing your post. Please don't mind it.

Comment: @konsolebox I saw the edit you were entering, but I can't hard code that.. I have times when I need to have no call back and others that it'll call a different script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are still some parts of your script that I don't understand, or not sure it does really work, but about your question, I think your callback could only work if you place it on a function like:

```
function mycallback {
    php /srv/www/scripts/mage/install-invoke-app.php
}
```

And call your `install_repolist` function as

```
install_repolist $gitRepos 0 mycallback
```

That should make your php command call with the file argument work but there is one thing: I don't think values of `gitRepos` could actually be passed like that.

Most parts of your code has variables that actually needed to be quoted around double quotes `""`. One problem with it is that your php command would just end up in the final place where it is executed as one single argument `php` and no longer with the file due to word splitting.

Comment: I can't hard code that.. I have times when I need to have no call back and others that it'll call a different script, also there are times that the files will be pulled from an extrnal source so I can really do it that way.. but yes the gitRepos does work, in fact the whole does work less the php not getting invoked and being treated like a bush script.. I think..

Comment: dang you may be right that I need to do it as a function.. I'll get back on that.. tk

Comment: so just calling this `mycallback` and the php doesn't run.. did `    mycallback() {
        php /srv/www/scripts/mage/install-invoke-app.php
    }
    mycallback ` with no luck

Comment: @jeremyBass_DC You can add -x option when calling your script to see how they are actually executed e.g. `bash -x base.sh` if `base.sh` if the starting script. By the way I didn't see the snapshot photo until now. So the problem could actually be on the php script?

Comment: `php -x path/file.php' just gets me a invalid option

Comment: I actually meant `bash -x` on a bash script not php.